# Plotting 'vectors' with different colors in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

My data are :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import *
import matplotlib

my_vectors =[['120819152800063',10,189, 8],
 ['120819152800063', 10,184, 8],
 ['120819152800063', 0,190, 43],
 ['120819152800067', 8,67, 10],
 ['120819152800067', 8,45, 10],
 ['120819152800073', 10,31, 8],
 ['120819152800073', 10,79, 8],
 ['120819152800073', 7,102, 25],
 ['120819152800075', 125,0, 13]]
```

I'm trying to plot vectors to represent the data, but i cheated(i represent a line which represent the body of the vector and 2 points for the beginning and the end), I just want to color the body of each 'vector'.

```
timeString = zip(*my_vectors)[0]
timeDatetime=[datetime.strptime(aTime, '%y%m%d%H%M%S%f') for aTime in timeString]
timeDate=matplotlib.dates.date2num(timeDatetime)
# Represent the data time
X = tuple([int(x) for x in timeString])
# Represent the data sender
Y = zip(*my_vectors)[1]
# represent the data type 
U = zip(*my_vectors)[2]
# represent the data receiver
V = zip(*my_vectors)[3]

# the 'body' of the vectors
plt.vlines(timeDate,Y,V,colors='r')
# the beginning of the vectors
plt.plot_date(timeDate,Y,'b.',xdate=True)
# the end of the vectors
plt.plot_date(timeDate,V,'y.')
plt.show()
```

To have a better read of my data, i need to change color for each data type but i don't know how many data type i'll have.
How can i do this?

I have read this question but i don't really understand the answer :

[Setting different color for each series in scatter plot on matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236566/setting-different-color-for-each-series-in-scatter-plot-on-matplotlib-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access different colors by using a colormap. The module [matplotlib.cm](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html) provides colormaps or you can c[reate your own](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html). [This demo](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/show_colormaps.html) shows the available colormaps and their names. Colormaps contain 256 different colors. You can iterate through your data and assign a different color to each vector as is done in the example you linked to. If you have more than 256 data points you'll need to repeat colors or use a larger colormap but you might get into the limits of spectral resolution anyway.

Here's an example based on your question.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

# Some fake data
timeDate = np.arange(256)
Y = timeDate * 1.1 + 2
V = timeDate * 3 + 1

# Select the color map named rainbow
cmap = cm.get_cmap(name='rainbow')

# Plot each vector with a different color from the colormap. 
for ind, (t, y, v) in enumerate(zip(timeDate, Y, V)):
    plt.vlines(t,y,v ,color = cmap(ind))

plt.show()
```

[image: plot using a color map on vlines]

Alternately, you can access the RGBA values from the colormap directly:

```
plt.vlines(timeDate,Y,V,colors=cmap(np.arange(256)))
```