# Bubble Chart Title and Colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, bubble-chart

In the following bubble chart, how can I:

1. Randomize the color of each bubble
2. Adjust the title (maybe upper) so it will not overlap with the graph tag on the far up left corner.

Here is my output:

[image: Bubble Chart]

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N=5
province=['Ontario','Quebec','BritishColumbia','Manitoba','NovaScoti']
size = [908.607,1356.547,922.509,552.329,651.036]
population = [12851821,7903001,4400057,1208268,4160000]
injuries = [625,752,629,1255,630]
plt.scatter(size,population,s=injuries)
for i in range(N):
    plt.annotate(province[i],xy=(size[i],population[i]))
plt.xlabel('Size(*1000km2)')
plt.ylabel('Population(ten million)')
plt.title('The Car Accidents Injuries Rate in 5 Canada Provinces')
plt.show
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can feed an array of `N` random numbers to a colormap to get `N` random colors, and then use that as the `color` argument when you call `plt.scatter`. `color` can be a list of colors the same length as the size and population lists, which will color each scatter point separately.
2. `plt.title` takes the argument `y` which will adjust the vertical placement of the title. In your case, try setting it to 1.05.

Here's your script, modified:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

N=5
province=['Ontario','Quebec','BritishColumbia','Manitoba','NovaScoti']
size = [908.607,1356.547,922.509,552.329,651.036]
population = [12851821,7903001,4400057,1208268,4160000]
injuries = [625,752,629,1255,630]

# Choose some random colors
colors=cm.rainbow(np.random.rand(N))

# Use those colors as the color argument
plt.scatter(size,population,s=injuries,color=colors)
for i in range(N):
    plt.annotate(province[i],xy=(size[i],population[i]))
plt.xlabel('Size(*1000km2)')
plt.ylabel('Population(ten million)')

# Move title up with the "y" option
plt.title('The Car Accidents Injuries Rate in 5 Canada Provinces',y=1.05)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) For the colours I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236566/setting-different-color-for-each-series-in-scatter-plot-on-matplotlib) with 3 solutions
one of which is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

x = np.arange(10)
ys = [i+x+(i*x)**2 for i in range(10)]

colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(ys)))
for y, c in zip(ys, colors):
    plt.scatter(x, y, color=c)
```

2) For the title overlap, you can remove the overlap by resizing the window. You can set the window size ([check](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_size_inches) `set_size_inches`).