# Need to visualize a python dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on a clustering algorithm which takes input from an excel file imported with pandas as a list. The list is divided into data blocks of like 8 floating points represented by `k[0], k[1].....k[7]` (the index numbers correspond to values in the dictionary). The cluster is represented in dictionary form. An example of my cluster output is

```
cluster = {0: [0, 2, 4, 5, 6], 1: [1], 2: [3, 7]}
```

Is there a way to have a scatter plot so that `[0, 2, 4, 5, 6]` is plotted with one color, `[1]` in another color, `[3,7]` in another color. Essentially, each cluster should be marked with the same color. I would like to know how to map this list to colors (preferably as many colors as the number of clusters in the clustering algorithm which is known beforehand). I am working with matplotlib in python and am completely lost as to how to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you looked at colormap implementation?
[Stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236566/setting-different-color-for-each-series-in-scatter-plot-on-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do a scatter for each list of numbers as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cluster = {0: [0, 2, 4, 5, 6], 1: [1], 2: [3, 7]}
colours = ['green', 'orange', 'red']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for colour, (x, ys) in zip(colours, cluster.items()):
    ax.scatter([x] * len(ys), ys, c=colour, linewidth=0, s=50)

plt.show()
```

Giving you:

[image: multi coloured scatter plot]

To extend this to use the colour map, `colours` could be constructed as:

```
colours = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(cluster)))
```

e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

cluster = {0: [0, 2, 4, 5, 6], 1: [1], 2: [3, 7]}
colours = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(cluster)))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for colour, (x, ys) in zip(colours, cluster.items()):
    ax.scatter([x] * len(ys), ys, c=colour, linewidth=0, s=50)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you @ Martin Evans. This would definitely serve the purpose. I just realized, I really do not need to plot all the points that make up the index number which was what I had been trying to achieve but it isn't necessary.