# Pandas How to group columns by their values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([2,2,6,9,7,6,2,9,7,11], columns=['cat1','cat2','cat3','cat4','cat5','cat6','cat7','cat8','cat9','cat10'])
```

Inside this df, there is only 1 row.

How can I group these columns according to their values and display the clusters of columns in a plot?

[image]

Currently, this is my code, but it displays wrong info

```
grouped_cats = df.groupby(by= lambda value: value, axis = 1)
list(grouped_cats)[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't figure out your use case but i think file code should help

```
columns=['cat1','cat2','cat3','cat4','cat5','cat6','cat7','cat8','cat9','cat10']
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,2,6,9,7,6,2,9,7,11]],columns=columns )

grouped_cats = {}
for i,val in enumerate(df.iloc[0]):
    if val in grouped_cats:
        grouped_cats[val].append(columns[i])
    else:
        grouped_cats[val]= [columns[i]]
```

> Output = {2: ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat7'],  6: ['cat3', 'cat6'],  9:
> ['cat4', 'cat8'],  7: ['cat5', 'cat9'],  11: ['cat10']}

The easiest way of visualisation that i can think of is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colours = ['green', 'orange', 'red','blue','black']
cluster = {2: ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat7'],
 6: ['cat3', 'cat6'],
 9: ['cat4', 'cat8'],
 7: ['cat5', 'cat9'],
 11: ['cat10']}

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xticks([i for i in range(2,12)] )
for colour, (x, ys) in zip(colours, cluster.items()):
    ax.scatter([x] * len(ys), ys, c=colour, linewidth=0, s=50)


plt.show()
```

Another way to visualise is for each of the unique values in your data, count the number of labels associated and plot the scatter plot for annotate with class names.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colours = ['green', 'orange', 'red','blue','black']

cluster = {2: ['c1', 'c2', 'c7'],
 6: ['c3', 'c6'],
 9: ['c4', 'c8'],
 7: ['c5', 'c9'],
 11: ['c10']}

z = [len(cluster[ke]) for ke in cluster ]
y = [ke for ke in cluster ]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xticks([i for i in range(2,12)] )
ax.scatter(y, z, c=colours)
for i,val in enumerate(cluster):
    ax.annotate(','.join(cluster[val]), (y[i], z[i]))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Prayalankar, this data result is what I am looking for. Is it possible to also provide code to plot them nicely in clusters?

Comment: For plot part referred from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087575/need-to-visualize-a-python-dictionary

Comment: hi @Pray if we use scatter plot, how can we show multiple categories within 1 dot?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by the cluster plot. My thinking, best way to visualize this spread is by scatter plot. You can Transpose and rename if needed

```
df.T.reset_index().plot(kind='scatter', x='index', y=0)
```

[image]

Or even plot

```
df.T.reset_index().plot(kind='bar', x='index', y=0)
```

[image]

Following your comment and clarificationlets groupby and dict

```
df.T.reset_index().groupby(0).agg(list).to_dict()

{'index': {2: ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat7'],
  6: ['cat3', 'cat6'],
  7: ['cat5', 'cat9'],
  9: ['cat4', 'cat8'],
  11: ['cat10']}}
```

Comment: Hi @wwnde, this is exactly I have already plotted.   What I want is groups of names under same count/value number. E.g. `{2:['cat1', 'cat2','cat7'], 6: ['cat3','cat6','cat9',],....}` and then plot nicely.

Comment: Can we then try `df.T.reset_index().groupby(0).agg(list).to_dict()`