# Scatterplot - shift points for dx (dt) in a timeseries

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a code which assigns a legend to each element of the datalist (17 different colors), including the same color of the errorbars.

In the process I have found very useful answers for the coloring of the plots within a loop (like in the post: [Setting different color for each series in scatter plot on matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12236566/7541421)) , for which I get an image like this:

[image]

The **question** is: **how to offset each series for a dx for every iSub when having a timeseries as x axis so that the scatter plots of each iSub don't overlap?**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def datetime_range(start, end, delta):
    current = start
    while current < end:
        yield current
        current += delta


nSub = 17
nTimes = 34

datalist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q']


DATA = np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=50.0, size=(nSub,nTimes))

DZ = np.random.rand(nSub,nTimes)

timelist = [dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for dt in 
   datetime_range(datetime(2012, 1, 1), datetime(2014, 8, 1), 
   timedelta(weeks=4))]
datelist = [datetime.strptime(timelist[i], '%Y-%m-%d') for i in range(len(timelist))]

fig, ax = plt.subplots (nrows=1, ncols=1)

colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(datalist)))

for isub in range(len(datalist)):

    ax.scatter(datelist, DATA[isub], label=datalist[isub], color = colors[isub]) 
    ax.errorbar(datelist, DATA[isub], yerr = DZ[isub], color = colors[isub], fmt='o', markersize=8, capsize=20)

    ax.set_xlim([datetime(2011,12,1).toordinal(), datetime(2015,1,1).toordinal()] )

    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)

    ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

fig.set_size_inches(40,20)
```

Comment: You can specify the color of the error bars using the keyword `ecolor` in your `ax.errorbar()` method. See here: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html

Comment: yes, I saw this but how do you specify it so it matches the colors of the scatterplots? what should the `ecolor` be set equal to?

Comment: The default behavior according to the docs is that the error bar colors will match the associated scatter data color.

Comment: however it didn't prove to work for a more complex dataset. See changes in the code above.

Comment: There is a comma missing between the `color` and `fmt` argument in `color = colors[isub] fmt='o'`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I corrected it @ImportanceOfBeingErnest