# Equivalent of pcolormesh for irregular points

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using [pcolormesh](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) on a 2-D NumPY array of points M, so

```
pcolormesh(X,Y,M)
```

plots a grid of colors where the X-axis range labels correspond to X[i], Y-axis range labels correspond to Y[j], and the color plotted at point (i,j) corresponds to the level of M[i,j].

I would also like to plot the same thing but where I have a 1-D array M[i], and the color plotted at point (X[i], Y[i]) corresponds to the level of M[i].

I don't see any out of the box solution for this in matplotlib.  Is there one?  This is the closest I could come up with, taking a cue from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236566/setting-different-color-for-each-series-in-scatter-plot-on-matplotlib):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

def intensityplot(x,y,z):
    z=z/z.max()
    colors = cm.rainbow(z)
    for X,Y,Z in zip(x,y,colors):
        plt.scatter([X],[Y], color=Z)
```

Comment: Matplotlib provides e.g.  `tripcolor` or `tricontourf`. Can you go into detail about the requirements and rather ask about actual problems with implementations?

Comment: I have an original 4x4 matrix and then I want to subdivide it into 8x8 matrix and plot the points from the original 4x4 matrix, leaving dark spots for what I haven't filled in yet in the subdivided matrix.  Since the results above are ugly, what I've done is cleanly subdivided by a factor of two so it is easy to fill in the old points and continue using pcolormesh as before.