# How can I change colors in a scatter plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

I have two problems.

First I want to change the blue of 'column_B' to light gray (code: `#e9e9e9`).

Second, I want to delete the Price section of the label that appears due to the `size` option.

```
sns.scatterplot(x = "Column_A", 
            y = "Column_C", 
            hue = 'Column_B',
            size = 'price',
            sizes=(50, 500),
            data = df)
```

I want this result...

[image: expected result] image!!

Comment: From here https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html, giving the `palette` keyword a list of 3 colors will change the colors into what you want.

Using `legend = 'brief'` should remove what you don't want into the legend.

Comment: To change the color you can use a color map that varies depending on column B. You can follow the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236566/setting-different-color-for-each-series-in-scatter-plot-on-matplotlib).

Comment: @Liris I tried your 'legend option' guide, but the result was the same. and I'll try the 'palette'~ Thank you.

Comment: @JosephRajchwald  Thank you for your attention. I will read the example and try it! ~