# ValueError: 'c' argument has 2 elements which is not acceptable for use, when trying python matplotlib scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I have been trying to debug my code for a while, and i need help in trying to plot a scatterplot.
When i tried to plot it, it gave me an error stated:

> ValueError: 'c' argument has 2 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 48, 'y' with size 48.

The dataset: https://data.gov.sg/dataset/monthly-revalidation-of-coe-of-existing-vehicles?view_id=b228d20d-5771-48ec-9d7b-bb52351c0f7d&resource_id=e62a59fd-ee9f-43ec-ac69-58dc5c8045be

My code:

```
import numpy as np        #importing numpy as np declaring as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   #importing matplotlib pyplot as plt

title = "COE revalidation"     #title of the output
titlelen = len(title)   
print("{:*^{titlelen}}".format(title, titlelen=titlelen+6))
print()

recoe = np.genfromtxt("data/annual-revalidation-of-certificate-of-entitlement-coe-of-existing-vehicles.csv",  #loading dataset, storing it as recoe
                      dtype=(int,"U12","U18",int),
                      delimiter=",",
                      names=True)
years = np.unique(recoe["year"])     #extracting unique values from year column, storing it as years
type = np.unique(recoe["type"])      #extracting unique values from type column, storing it as type
category = np.unique(recoe["category"])  #extracting unique values from category column, storing it as category
category5 = recoe[recoe["type"]=="5 Year"]   #extracting coe 5 year, storing it as category5
category10 = recoe[recoe["type"]=="10 Year"]  #extracting coe 10 year, storing it as category10

category5numbers = category5["number"]   #extracting 'number' from category5 and storing it as category5numbers   (number of revalidation , 5 years)
category10numbers = category10["number"]    #extracting 'number' from category10 and storing it as category5numbers   (number of revalidation , 10 years)
    colours =['tab:blue', 'tab:orange'] 

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 6))
plt.scatter(category5numbers,category10numbers,c= colours ,linewidth=1,alpha=0.75,edgecolor='black',s=200)
plt.title("Scatter Plot of category5 versus category10")
plt.xlabel("number of category 5 revalidation")
plt.ylabel("number of category 10 revalidation")
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A point is represented matching the indexes of the 'x' and 'y' coordinates lists.

Now, let's figure out the problem. You get:

> ValueError: 'c' argument has 2 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 48, 'y' with size 48.

That means **the parameter 'c' in the scatter function has to to have the same size than 'x' and 'y' coordinates lists (category5numbers and category10numbers in your case)**. You can't pass a list with only 2 elements, because the way the 'c' parameter works (given the fact you are discarding setting the same color to all the points, which can be done by setting c to a single color format string), is the following:

- **every point will be mapped to a color matching the indexes in the 'xs' 'ys' and 'c' lists. There has to be a color specification for each point ...**

That said, **if you give only 2 colors for 48 points, the scatter function does not know what to do!**

From the [scatter docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html), you get that 'c' can be ...

[image]

So, summing up, you will have to:

1. create a list to represent the colors
2. **fill all the 48 positions with the color representative you want**
3. Pass it to the scatter function

Check out the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32649740/9932220) to see how you can determine the colors, and to understand what I mean by saying *" same size for 'x' 'y' coordinates lists and 'c' "*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to make a scatter plot using two variables but a single factor. You can't do this. You can, however, pass a list of colors if you can divide your data into multiple factors. The `Category` column in your data set can be used to separate your data.