# How to use two different color for two different class of data while plotting data using python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

**What I tried**

```
# import libraries
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# function for plotting data
def plot_data(data):
    X_1 = data["x1"]
    X_2 = data["x2"]
    Y = data["y"]

    # Create data frame with randomly selected x and y positions
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns=["x1","x2"])
    

    # Add a column: the color depends on x1 and x2 values.
    value = (df["x1"] <= 7) & (df["x1"] > 0)
    df['color']= np.where( value==True , "#9b59b8", "#3498db")

    # plot
    sns.regplot(data=df, x="x1", y="x2", fit_reg=False, scatter_kws= 
                {'facecolors':df['color']})



    plt.title("Datasets for Neural network")
    plt.xlabel("X_1")
    plt.ylabel("X_2")

    plt.show()

data = pd.read_csv('./assets/data/data0/data.csv')
plot_data(data)
```

**Output**

[image]

This is not the output I want. I want two different colors for two different clusters of data.
[image]

Data on the left needs to be in purple and on right it should be in blue.

**My dataset in CSV**

y,x1,x2

1.0000,2.6487,4.5192

1.0000,1.5438,2.4443

1.0000,1.8990,4.2409

1.0000,2.4711,5.8097

1.0000,3.3590,6.4423

1.0000,3.2406,5.8097

1.0000,3.8128,6.3917

1.0000,4.4441,6.8725

1.0000,3.6747,6.7966

**Resources I tried**

[StackOverflow q/a, didn't resolve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236566/setting-different-color-for-each-series-in-scatter-plot-on-matplotlib)

Took help from [this](https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/45-control-color-of-each-marker-seaborn) site. But, does not resolve my problem when I want to plot features x1 vs x2 and want the different color for the different cluster.

How could I do that?

Comment: You set a different color if `x1 <7`, while you want a different color if `x1 < x2`. Does the following give the desired result?
`value = (df["x1"] <= df["x2"])`

Comment: @dkruit Thank you for pointing out the error I was making in writing conditions. It works!

Comment: As the issue is resolved by adjusting the existing comparison line in the code, I'm voting to close the question as caused by a typo / not reproducible.