# Colorize based on condition

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am having the following code to display a plot. I would like to conditionally format the values based on a threshold of 0.05.

```
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba

# Generate x-axis
x = np.linspace(0, len(data_formula), len(data_formula))
colors = np.where(data_formula <= 0.05, "blue", "green")
plt.plot(x, data_formula, c=colors)

# Add labels and title
plt.ylabel('Volume')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.title('Energy')

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately I do receive the error: `array(['blue', 'blue', 'blue', ..., 'blue', 'blue', 'blue'], dtype='<U5') is not a valid value for color`, which indicates that I have passed the wrong value to the color parameter. I have tried it with lists, etc. But it doesn't seem to work. What went wrong? Does the argument `color` just not accept any datastructure or is the format wrong?

For reference: `data_formula` is defined as follow:

```
def energy(x):
    
    return (x**2)

data_formula = np.apply_along_axis(energy, axis=0, arr=data_normalized)
```

It is of datatype: `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: Can you show part of `data_formula`?

Comment: My suggestion is to separate it into two curves: a blue curve and a green curve.

Comment: @memristor I have edited the question to provide further information. Thanks for mentioning this :)

Comment: You should try `seaborn` module, it is more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using different colors you should split data segments each one with its color:

```
#%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, len(data_formula), len(data_formula))
crossings = np.where(np.diff(data_formula > 0.05))[0]
start = 0

# Plot segments
for ind in crossings:
    plt.plot(x[start:ind+1], data_formula[start:ind+1], 
             color='blue' if data_formula[start] <= 0.05 else 'green')
    start = ind+1

plt.plot(x[start:], data_formula[start:], 
         color='blue' if data_formula[start] <= 0.05 else 'green')

plt.ylabel('Volume')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.title('Energy')
plt.show()
```

I assumed your data is like:

```
data_formula = np.array([0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0])
```

If instead of segments you just want the points do the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


for x, y in enumerate(data_formula):
    plt.scatter(x, y, color='blue' if y <= 0.05 else 'green')

    
plt.ylabel('Volume')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.title('Energy')
plt.show()
```

this last one inspired from [stackoverflow: different colors series scatter plot on matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236566/setting-different-color-for-each-series-in-scatter-plot-on-matplotlib).

If the previous answer takes to much time try:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data_formula = np.array([0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0])

xy_blue = [(x, y) for x, y in enumerate(data_formula) if y <= 0.05]
xy_gree = [(x, y) for x, y in enumerate(data_formula) if y > 0.05]

plt.scatter([t[0] for t in xy_blue], [t[1] for t in xy_blue], color='blue')
plt.scatter([t[0] for t in xy_gree], [t[1] for t in xy_gree], color='green')

    
plt.ylabel('Volume')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.title('Energy')
plt.show()
```

Anyway, I've never see a plot to take more than 30sec so maybe you have to reload your environment, you have way too much data to plot and should make different plots, or you have a low RAM issue.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Unfortunately the loop takes too long to run (30+ mins in). Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I'll update my answer.